# Update Grid Panel on Tab Switch in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs

I have two separate tabs (Tab A & Tab B). These two tabs share a single store wherein each are in their respective indices. `[0] - A` , and `[1] - B`.

My controller initializes the load upon click on its menu leaf such as:

```
oMe.control({
  '#role-permission-grid-panel': {

    edit: oMe.save,

    beforerender: oMe.loadData,

  },
  '#roles-applicationtype button': {
    click: oMe.filterByApplication
  }
});
```

`applicationtype button` is the filter where tab switching of loaded data happens.

When trying to catch the value of the current filter, the controller successfully shows which one was clicked. However, this no longer refreshes the grid panel data.

**SampleGridPanel /view**:

```
console.log('Application',oController.sDefaultToggle);
```

Simply put, I update the data from `SampleController`, and try to catch it from my `SampleGridPanel` by calling `filterApplication`. My `SampleGridPanel` only loads the store **once** due to `initComponent`. I want to pass the updated data (in this case the selected tab) from the `controller` to the `view`. How do I notify my view that this change occurred when it only identifies data on initial load?

I'm also a bit confused. On my controller, when calling `oMe.loadData` `beforerender`, it knows the last tabbed value, but when I call `oMe.loadData` from a custom filter function, it no longer reloads the entire store. It only loads the filtered information based on the filter value.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the [`activate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-activate) and [`deactivate`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-deactivate) events of the tabpanel. These are also available in older versions of ExtJS.

If you are using ExtJS 6, you should really consider using [`ChainedStore`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.ChainedStore).

- A Store contains the data.
- The grids aren't bound to the store, but to a ChainedStore each.
- The ChainedStores have their source set to the store, and use different filter to only get the data that should be shown in their respective grid.

Please note that as of ExtJS 6.0.1 there were bugs in ExtJS that exhibited when combining `ChainedStore` with `GroupingFeature` or `CellEditing`. These should be fixed in ExtJS 6.0.2.

Comment: I am using ExtJS 4.2. I needed to re-check the values loaded when the tab switches. Problem is, it no longer goes over the values once it loads. Is there a way, for instance, to have my toolbar trigger a click event and then check the values, and if it satisfies adds/removes the element (i.e. a button item)?